# What is the difference between cognition and artificial intelligence in the context of robotics?

Tags: terminology, artificial-intelligence

A lot of research work is being conducted on artificial intelligence and robotics. Terms like cognitive robotics are used. What is the difference between cognitive robotics and artificial intelligence or are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

The distinction isn't rigid, but it has to do with whether the program controlling the robot is designed to mimic the human mind in some way.

If the robot is a model of human cognition, then the term cognitive robotics is sometimes used. Artificial Intelligence is a general term for software that behaves in an intelligent manner. There are plenty of intelligent robots that are not thought to be models of how the human mind works, because they achieve their intelligent behavior in a manner that is inconsistent with what we know about cognitive psychology and cognitive neuroscience.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please highlight models if any in what way human mind represents knowledge and what is the definition of cognition?

Comment: That's a very broad question. There are thousands of journal articles related to models of how the human mind represents knowledge.

Comment: Could you define in your answer please, what is cognition, cognitive science and semantics if the robot is going to perform reasoning and decision making. Thank you for your effort